# NullPointerException running servlet

Tags: servlets, nullpointerexception

) When I run my servlet i get the following error: Can anybody see what this is about? I am trying to get startDate and endDate from a form. I guess it is something about my simpleDateFormat, but I cannot see what I have done wrong?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1234)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:335)
    at getHoursSQL.doPost(getHoursSQL.java:40)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

My servlet looks like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/getHoursSQL")
public class getHoursSQL extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/NekiWork";
        Connection connection=null;

        try {
            //Load database driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            //Connection to the database
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
            //Getting the data from database

            String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 60)) AS Allday_hours FROM Workdata "
                    + " WHERE Date = ? AND Date = ? ";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd");

            java.util.Date util_StartDate = format.parse( req.getParameter("startDate") );  
            java.sql.Date sql_StartDate = new java.sql.Date( util_StartDate.getTime() );

            java.util.Date util_EndDate = format.parse( req.getParameter("endDate") );      
            java.sql.Date sql_EndDate = new java.sql.Date( util_EndDate.getTime() );
                pst.setDate( 1, sql_StartDate );
                pst.setDate(2, sql_EndDate );
                System.out.println(req.getParameter("startDate"));                          
                System.out.println(req.getParameter("endDate"));
            //Show the result from database
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            float Allday_hours_sum = 0;
                while (rs.next()){                                      
                    Allday_hours_sum += rs.getFloat("Allday_hours"); 

                }   
                res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");          
                res.getWriter().print(Allday_hours_sum); 

                pst.close();

        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

            System.out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {

            try {
                if (connection != null) connection.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException ignored){
                System.out.println(ignored);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edited CODE:

```
PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

            java.util.Date util_startDate = format.parse( req.getParameter("startDate") );  
            java.sql.Date sql_startDate = new java.sql.Date( util_startDate.getTime() );

            java.util.Date util_endDate = format.parse( req.getParameter("endDate") );      
            java.sql.Date sql_endDate = new java.sql.Date( util_endDate.getTime() );

                pst.setDate( 1, sql_startDate );
                pst.setDate(2, sql_endDate );
                System.out.println(req.getParameter("startDate"));                          
                System.out.println(req.getParameter("endDate"));
```

Comment: Does `req.getParameter("startDate")` and `req.getParameter("endDate")` give you a non-null value? You can use a debugger to find out.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. They give me the 
print.out : 
2014-03-02
2014-03-05
So that should be correct, right?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat.parse() expects the date format, but it is giving you something different.

Comment: hm have been looking at it. As I see it, it gives med the date format, But that is of course wrong :-/ since it dosent work. Can you give a hint?

Comment: pls show me the dao page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how did you mention like `pst.setDate(1, sql_EndDate );pst.setDate(2, sql_EndDate );` both of them same name in the servlet page. 
I thing the problem is here and your doing like this as:

```
  pst.setDate( 1, sql_StartDate );
  pst.setDate(2, sql_EndDate );
```

and you should use this type like servlet:

```
user.setDob(dob);
```

the user is following like insert part in dao:

```
public void addUser(User user)
    preparedStatement.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(user.getDob().getTime()));
```

***sameple code***:

```
 SimpleDateFormat fm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date startDate = fm.parse(req.getParameter("startDate"); 
    pst.setSDate(1,startDate);

 SimpleDateFormat fm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date startDate = fm.parse(req.getParameter("endDate"); 
    pst.setEDate(2,startDate);
```

Comment: Hm that seems wrong. But thanks for your time and answer

Comment: @Julie24, what are you telling your doing this naming mistake you should must change that...look at my sample code

Comment: thanks a lot for your time:-) The thing I do not understand is why pst.setDate(1,startDate);
should be:
pst.setDaaate(1,startDate);